# Need to create a function for a repeating piece of code

Tags: vb.net, function, visual-studio-2015, repeat

I have the following function in my code.

```
  Private Function MedTuboFuncPCT() As List(Of Decimal)
    Dim a, Div, MedTubo1, DivExa, Div1, Div2, Div3, Div4, Div5 As Decimal
    Dim b, MedTubo2, Div11, Div22, Div33, Div44, Div55 As Decimal
    a = Me.Controls("MeasurePCT" & ContadorGlobal).Text
    Div = 2
    If a > 6029 Then
        Te180 = Te180 + 1
        b = (a + 21) / 2
        Div = Div + 1
        If b / Div <= LimiteGlobalSeparador Then
            DivExa = b / Div
            Div1 = DivExa - 19
            Div2 = DivExa
            Div3 = DivExa - 30.5
            MedTubo1 = Div1 + Div2 + Div3
            Div11 = DivExa - 30.5
            Div22 = DivExa
            Div33 = DivExa - 31
            MedTubo2 = Div11 + Div22 + Div33
        Else
            Div = Div + 1
            If b / Div <= LimiteGlobalSeparador Then
                DivExa = b / Div
                Div1 = DivExa - 19
                Div2 = DivExa
                Div3 = DivExa
                Div4 = DivExa - 30.5
                MedTubo1 = Div1 + Div2 + Div3 + Div4
                Div11 = DivExa - 30.5
                Div22 = DivExa
                Div33 = DivExa
                Div44 = DivExa - 31
                MedTubo2 = Div11 + Div22 + Div33 + Div44
            Else
                Div = Div + 1
                If b / Div <= LimiteGlobalSeparador Then
                    DivExa = b / Div
                    Div1 = DivExa - 19
                    Div2 = DivExa
                    Div3 = DivExa
                    Div4 = DivExa
                    Div5 = DivExa - 30.5
                    MedTubo1 = Div1 + Div2 + Div3 + Div4 + Div5
                    Div11 = DivExa - 30.5
                    Div22 = DivExa
                    Div33 = DivExa
                    Div44 = DivExa
                    Div55 = DivExa - 31
                    MedTubo2 = Div11 + Div22 + Div33 + Div44 + Div55
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Else
        If a <= LimiteGlobalSeparador Then
            MedTubo1 = a - 29
        Else
            If a / Div <= LimiteGlobalSeparador Then
                DivExa = (a + 21) / Div
                Div1 = DivExa - 19
                Div2 = DivExa - 31
                MedTubo1 = Div1 + Div2
            Else
                Div = Div + 1
                If a / Div <= LimiteGlobalSeparador Then
                    DivExa = (a + 21) / Div
                    Div1 = DivExa - 19
                    Div2 = DivExa
                    Div3 = DivExa - 31
                    MedTubo1 = Div1 + Div2 + Div3
                Else
                    Div = Div + 1
                    If a / Div <= LimiteGlobalSeparador Then
                        DivExa = (a + 21) / Div
                        Div1 = DivExa - 19
                        Div2 = DivExa
                        Div3 = DivExa
                        Div4 = DivExa - 31
                        MedTubo1 = Div1 + Div2 + Div3 + Div4
                    Else
                        Div = Div + 1
                        If a / Div <= LimiteGlobalSeparador Then
                            DivExa = (a + 21) / Div
                            Div1 = DivExa - 19
                            Div2 = DivExa
                            Div3 = DivExa
                            Div4 = DivExa
                            Div5 = DivExa - 31
                            MedTubo1 = Div1 + Div2 + Div3 + Div4 + Div5
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Dim iList As New List(Of Decimal)
    iList.Add(MedTubo1)
    iList.Add(Div1)
    iList.Add(Div2)
    iList.Add(Div3)
    iList.Add(Div4)
    iList.Add(Div5)
    If a > 6029 Then
        iList.Add(MedTubo2)
        iList.Add(Div11)
        iList.Add(Div22)
        iList.Add(Div33)
        iList.Add(Div44)
        iList.Add(Div55)
    End If
    If Div3 = 0 Then
        SoporteTT90 = SoporteTT90 + 1
    Else
        If Div4 = 0 Then
            SoporteTT90 = SoporteTT90 + 2
        Else
            If Div5 = 0 Then
                SoporteTT90 = SoporteTT90 + 3
            Else
                SoporteTT90 = SoporteTT90 + 4
            End If
        End If
    End If
    If Div33 = 0 Then
        SoporteTT90 = SoporteTT90 + 1
    Else
        If Div44 = 0 Then
            SoporteTT90 = SoporteTT90 + 2
        Else
            If Div55 = 0 Then
                SoporteTT90 = SoporteTT90 + 3
            Else
                SoporteTT90 = SoporteTT90 + 4
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Return iList
End Function
```

The last part of the code is this:

```
    If Div3 = 0 Then
        SoporteTT90 = SoporteTT90 + 1
    Else
        If Div4 = 0 Then
            SoporteTT90 = SoporteTT90 + 2
        Else
            If Div5 = 0 Then
                SoporteTT90 = SoporteTT90 + 3
            Else
                SoporteTT90 = SoporteTT90 + 4
            End If
        End If
    End If
    If Div33 = 0 Then
        SoporteTT90 = SoporteTT90 + 1
    Else
        If Div44 = 0 Then
            SoporteTT90 = SoporteTT90 + 2
        Else
            If Div55 = 0 Then
                SoporteTT90 = SoporteTT90 + 3
            Else
                SoporteTT90 = SoporteTT90 + 4
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

That last part, repeats itself a lot in different functions. Is there a way to make a function for that code? The problem I'm facing is that when I try to create a new function I don't have the values of Div1, Div2, Div3, etc, since they are part of my main function. How do I make a function that can use those values, or how can I get a function that recreates that piece of code. Hope I'm clear enough. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to pass the values of Div1, Div2, Div3 as parameters in your function call. So you would need to adjust the scope of these variables so that the function that calls them will be able to access their values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you guide me a little bit on how to do that please?

Comment: Yeah, like @Maertin said, any function will need access to these values, so you would need to pass them in your function call (eg `myDivFunction(Div1, Div2, Div3,...Div55)` or change the scope of the variables to globals. Another option would be to make all those Divs an array so you're just passing around one variable instead of a dozen or so. You do have a lot of repeated code that could be placed in functions.

Comment: Oh, you have no idea the amount of repeating code I have. That's just a part of the program, you would die if you'd see the whole code. I'm very new at programming, and I'm doing something for my company so I was just aiming for a functional program. But as I try to make the program better and add things, I get into the problem that I have too much code. I'll try to see how to pass my variables, I'll look for some info. Thank you.

Comment: I just figured out how to to pass the values, I had forgotten something when creating the function. Thank you for your help you 2.